# what are DP and DQ in Encryption by RSA in c#

Tags: rsa

I want to know about these tags in RSA Encryption by private Key. when I use this code:

```
using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize))
    {
        publicKey = provider.ToXmlString(false);
        privateKey = provider.ToXmlString(true);
    }
```

It create this xml:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus>…</Modulus>
   <Exponent>…</Exponent>
   <P>…</P>
   <Q>…</Q>
   <DP>…</DP>
   <DQ>…</DQ>
   <InverseQ>…</InverseQ>
   <D>…</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I know that $p$ and $q$ are the primes number, but I dont know what are DP and DQ and why we need to InversQ and else...

is anyone explain these items for encryption?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DP is $d\bmod{p-1}$, similarly DQ is $d\bmod{q-1}$. InverseQ is $q^{-1}\bmod{p}$.

These are used in applying the [Chinese Remainder Theorem to RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm) decryption, which is an optimization technique.